# jenkins pipeline : How to execute a function on a list of agents in parallel?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I have a bunch of nodes serving labels `rhel6`, `rhel7`.

How do I execute `myFunc()` on any 2 nodes of `rhel6` and any 3 nodes `rhel7` - *in parallel*?

```
def slaveList = ['rhel6', 'rhel6', 'rhel7', 'rhel7', 'rhel7']

def stageFunc (String slaveLabel) {
  return {
        // Run this stage on any available node serving slaveLabel
        agent { label "${slaveLabel}" } // Error shown here.
        stage {
            myFunc()
        }
    } 
}

pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Start') {
            steps {
                script {
                    def stageMap = [:]
                    def i = 0
                    slaveList.each { s ->
                        stageMap[i] = stageFunc(s)
                        i++
                    }
                    parallel stageMap
                }
            }
        }        
    }
}
```

Error shown:
`java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'agent' found among steps [archive, ...`

Comment: You need to place your `stage`s inside the `parallel` and then place the `agent` inside those `stage`s.

Comment: I am doing the same ... but just using map and modular function.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this yet, but it should work.

```
def slaveList = ['rhel6', 'rhel6', 'rhel7', 'rhel7', 'rhel7']

def stageFunc (stage_name, slaveLabel) {
  return {
        // Run this stage on any available node serving slaveLabel
        stage(stage_name){
            node(slaveLabel) {   
                myFunc()
            }
        }

    } 
}

pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Start') {
            steps {
                script {
                    def stageMap = [:]
                    def i = 0
                    slaveList.each { s ->
                        stageMap[i] = stageFunc("Stage-${i}", s)
                        i++
                    }
                    parallel stageMap
                }
            }
        }        
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to define multiple stages in `stageFunc`?